# Version Oracle Data Access dll for Installed Oracle Client

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle11g

I develop some Asp.net application with Oracle database to store data. There is a command in codebehind of my project that cause an error. So if Is execute following command:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OracleConnection ConDatabase = new OracleConnection();
        // String ConnectionStrings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MetacatWFConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { TextBox1.Text = ex.ToString(); }

}
```

Then there is error displayed: 
[image]

That is `the provider not compatible with the version of oracle client`. I dont know why this happen. The version of my oracle client is `10.2.0.4.0` and my `oracle.dataaccess.dll` is  `2.112.3.0`. Is these relevant to each other. I dont know how to determined what version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` that match the version of Oracle client.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 112 in 2.112.3.0 means that your ASP.Programm expects an 11g2 client to be installed on your machine. You can update your Oracle client as it is backward compatible to a 10g database. Hope that helps.